# Cybersource Verify Payment Response

Tags: ruby, cybersource

I have documentation which says after we do payment from **cybersource** and we need to verify payment. And to **verify payment**,we have to verify **payload signature** with new generated signature from payload. But I am getting two different signature. I generated signature by excluding **:utf8** and **:signature** from parameters returned by cybersource. But generated signature **doesn't matches with signature returned by cybersource**. If anyone have idea then it will be a great help.

If you need more details please comment, I will update later.

Answer (score 1):

The request and response will have different signatures. The signatures are created in the same way, but with different fields from different objects.

The request object signature is built off the request object using the fields listed in the signed_field_names property the request.

The response object signature is built off the response object using the fields listed in the signed_field_names property of the response.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on how a merchant would "check" the response signature to determine that the response object has not been tampered with?  I have a security admin who can demonstrate to me how she can "hijack" the response and modify the decline and reason code  and therefore the order processing endpoint believes that the payment was successful.   How can this be prevented using a "signature check".

Comment: You recalculate what the response signature should be based on the data in the response. If any of the fields differ from what cybersource used to create the signature, your generated signature will not match the signature in the response.